# Unwrapping multiple optionals in swift

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I want to load a PDF that is in my application bundle into a CGPDFDocument.

Is there some way of calling a function that if any of the parameters that don't accept options have values that are nil, the function isn't called and nil is returned.

eg:

```c
let pdfPath : String? = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResouce("nac_06", ofType:"pdf")
//I want to do this
let data : NSData? = NSData(contentsOfFile:pdfPath)
//I have to do this
let data : NSData? = pdfPath != nil ? NSData(contentsOfFile:pdfPath) : nil
let doc : CGPDFDocumentRef? = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(data));
//pageView.pdf is optional, nicely this function accepts the document as an optional
pageView.pdfPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(doc, 1);
```

Because NSData.init?(contentsOfFile path:String), doesn't define `path` as optional, even though it is has an optional return value, I have to check before and if the parameter is nil, return nil. Is there some syntactic sugar for the `data` assignment (instead of the `?:` operator)?

Answer (score 3):

Either use multiple optional bindings separated by commas

```
func loadPDF() -> CGPDFDocumentRef? 
{
  if let pdfPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResouce("nac_06", ofType:"pdf"),
       data = NSData(contentsOfFile:pdfPath), 
       doc = GPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(data)) {
    return doc
  } else {
    return nil
  }
}
```

or use the `guard` statement

```
func loadPDF() -> CGPDFDocumentRef? 
{
  guard let pdfPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResouce("nac_06", ofType:"pdf") else { return nil }
  guard let data = NSData(contentsOfFile:pdfPath) else { return nil }
  return GPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(data))
}
```

All explicit type annotations are syntactic sugar and not needed.

**Edit:**

In your particular case you need only to check if the file exists and even this – the file is missing – is very unlikely in iOS. Another benefit is to be able to return a non-optional PDFDocument.

```
func loadPDF() -> CGPDFDocumentRef
{
  guard let pdfPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("nac_06", ofType:"pdf") else {
    fatalError("file nac_06.pdf does not exist")
  }
  let data = NSData(contentsOfFile:pdfPath)
  return CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(data!))!
}
```

Comment: Yeah I put the type annotions in the question just to make it clear what returned optionals. I saw I could use the if let statement, but putting a bunch of lines in that seperated by commas, seems ugly. I updated my question to be more succinct and clear

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you also don't want to continue with the execution of the function if `pdfPath` or `data` is nil. In this case, `guard` would be the best choice:

```
guard let pdfPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResouce("nac_06", ofType:"pdf") else {
    // eventually also report some error
    return
}

guard let data = NSData(contentsOfFile:pdfPath) else {
    // eventually also report some error
    return
}

// at this point you have a valid data object
```

You could also combine this into a single `guard` statement, to reduce the code duplication, you'll loose however in this case the possibility to know which of the two failed.

```
guard let pdfPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("nac_06", ofType:"pdf"),
    data = NSData(contentsOfFile:pdfPath) else {
        // eventually also report some error
        return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways to achieve this.

1. Extend `NSData` class and create your own `convenience init?` method
2. Use the `guard` statement

I prefer the second method:

```
func getPDF(path : String?) -> CGPDFDocumentRef?
{
    guard let filePath = path,
              data     = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath),
              pdf      = GPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(data)) else
    {
        return nil
    }
    return pdf
}
```

Call the method like:

```
let doc = getPDF(path : NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResouce("nac_06", ofType:"pdf"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something fancy by defining a custom operator to deal with this situation. For example:

```
infix operator ^> {associativity left precedence 150}

func ^><T, U>(arg: T?, f: T->U?) -> U?{
    if let arg = arg {
        return f(arg)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

The operator takes an optional left-side argument and a function that takes a non-optional and returns another optional as a right-side argument.

You could then write your code like this:

```
let pdfPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("nac_06", ofType:"pdf")
//the line below needs a NSData extension
let data = pdfPath ^> NSData.fileContents
let doc = data ^> CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData ^> CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider
//pageView.pdf is optional, nicely this function accepts the document as an optional
pageView.pdfPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(doc, 1)
```

Note that for this to work you need to add an extension to NSData, as you cannot map the `init(contentsOfFile:)` initializer to a generic function that can be passed to `^>`.

```
extension NSData {
    class func fileContents(path: String) -> NSData? {
        return NSData(contentsOfFile: path)
    }
}
```

---

The usage of the `^>` operator reverts however the order you write the function names, if you prefer having the function names in the same order as the original code, you can add a reversed operator that does the same thing:

```
infix operator ^< {associativity right precedence 150}

func ^< <T, U>(f: T->U?, arg: T?) -> U?{
    if let arg = arg {
        return f(arg)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

let pdfPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("nac_06", ofType:"pdf")
let data = NSData.fileContents ^< pdfPath
let doc = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider ^< CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData ^< data
//pageView.pdf is optional, nicely this function accepts the document as an optional
pageView.pdfPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(doc, 1)
```

Comment: I did this: https://ghostbin.com/paste/phn9k but annoyingly `try?`ing a function that returns an optional results in a double optional... (even though it's meant to be syntactic sugar for `do { try r = fn } catch { r = nil }` which doesn't result in a double optional.

Comment: why is try? intended for functions that return non optionals? Surely there are situations where a function that can return nil and throw an exception? (Something eg loading data, something could go wrong like no connection, but it could be successful connecting just there is no relevant data)

Comment: ah thanks that seems odd that one returns an optional but not the other.